# Finding the Inverse of $\frac{\phi_1}{(1-x)^2}-\phi_0$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, inverse-function

I am trying to find the inverse of

$$y = \frac{\phi_1}{(1-x)^2}-\phi_0$$

where $\phi_0,\phi_1$ are contants. I tried using logs,

$$ \log ( y + \phi_0) = \log(\phi_1) - 2 \log(1-x)$$

$$  ( \log ( y + \phi_0) - \log(\phi_1) ) / -2 =  \log(1-x) $$

$$  \exp ( \frac{( \log ( y + \phi_0) - \log(\phi_1) )}{-2}) =  1-x $$

$$  1-\exp ( \frac{( \log ( y + \phi_0) - \log(\phi_1) )}{-2}) =  x $$

This gives strange results

```
def y(lam,phi0,phi1):
    return ( (phi1 / (1.0-lam)**2) - phi0)

def y_inv(x,phi0,phi1):
    return 1.0 - np.exp ((np.log(x+phi0) - np.log(phi1)) / -2.0)

lam = 10.0
print y_inv(y(lam,10.0,20.0),10.0,20.0)
```

Says -8.0

Any reason anyone can think of this will not work?

Thanks,

Comment: Why would you use logs? Just rewrite the equation to $(1-x)^2 = \frac{\phi_1}{y + \phi_0}$ and split cases for $x > 1$, $x < 1$ ($x = 1$ is undefined).

Comment: Looking at the answers, I guess the lesson is whenever there is a square in the function, the inverse is never easy. Square of -2 or +2 are both 4, the inverse has to take that into account. I used logs so I could avoid $\pm$ for of square root, but I guess that is the wrong move.

Comment: $\log(x)$ is undefined for $x < 0$, hence you delete half of your domain. You won't avoid splitting cases here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why $ \log$ ??? We have $y+\phi_0=\frac{\phi_1}{(1-x)^2}$, or

$(1-x)^2= \frac{\phi_1}{y+ \phi_0}$. This gives a quadratic equation for $x$.

Answer (score 1):

let $$y=\frac{a}{(1-x)^2}-b$$ then we have
$$y+b=\frac{a}{(1-x)^2}$$ and
$$(1-x)^2=\frac{a}{y+b}$$ and we get
$$|1-x|=\sqrt{\frac{a}{y+b}}$$ if $$\frac{a}{y+b}\geq 0$$
this equation has two solutions

Answer (score 1):

There are some typos in your formulas.

If you really want to use logarithms to solve this for $x$, then you have to consider several cases:

$$y = \frac{\phi_1}{(1-x)^2}-\phi_0$$

$1)$ $y - \phi_0 >0$ and $ \phi_1 >0$. Then you can write:

$$\log (y-\phi_0)=\log \phi_1-2 \log|1-x|$$

$$\log|1-x|=\frac{1}{2} (\log \phi_1-\log (y-\phi_0))$$

$$\log|1-x|=\log \sqrt{ \frac{ \phi_1}{y- \phi_0}}$$

$$|1-x|=\sqrt{ \frac{ \phi_1}{y- \phi_0}}$$

Two solutions here, as the other users said.

$2)$ $y - \phi_0 <0$ and $ \phi_1 <0$. Then you can write:

$$\log (\phi_0-y)=\log (- \phi_1)-2 \log|1-x|$$

The rest continues in the same fashion and gives the same two solutions.

Other cases don't give any solutions, since they are inconsistent.